# Asp.net 4 Themes per users

Tags: asp.net, themes

Hello I'm developping an application in Asp.net. One of my goals is to assign a theme to users (users can choose (between 2 themes) their own theme.
How can I achieve this?
thanks  a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can set a theme in the [`Page_PreInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.theme.aspx) handler like

```
Page.Theme = "MyGreatestThemeEver";
```

For keeping the selected theme you can either use Session, Profile, Cookies or a custom table in your database.